# Регулярка номера телефона в строке

Tags: python

необходима регулярка для обнаружения номеров телефонов в строке на Python.

Примеры номеров:

```
+79261234567
89261234567
79261234567
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
```

Нашел в интернет такую: ((8|+7)[- ]?)?((?\d{3})?[- ]?)?[\d- ]{7,10}.

Но она не работает, как надо, выдает местами ерунду. Я так понял она заточена под валидацию.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
phones = ("+79261234567,"
          "89261234567,"
          "79261234567,"
          "+7 926 123 45 67,"
          "8(926)123-45-67,"
          "123-45-67,"
          "9261234567,"
          "79261234567,"
          "(495)1234567")

res = re.findall(r"(\+?7|8)?[\- ]?(\(?\d{3}\)?)?[\- ]?(\d{7}|\d[\-\d ]{5,7}\d)[ |\,]", phones + " ")
```

Вывод:

```
[('+7', '926', '1234567'),
 ('8', '926', '1234567'),
 ('7', '926', '1234567'),
 ('+7', '926', '123 45 67'),
 ('8', '(926)', '123-45-67'),
 ('', '', '123-45-67'),
 ('', '926', '1234567'),
 ('7', '926', '1234567'),
 ('', '(495)', '1234567')]
```

Если сильно надо, то можно дополнительно конкатенировать.

Answer (score 1):

Если возможно немного стандартизировать номера то можно попробовать так:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})"
num = """
+79261234567
89261234567
79261234568
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
"""
# Cтандартизируем номера удаляя все лишнее
# Без некоторых можно и обойтись
num = num.replace(" ", "")
num = num.replace("-", "")
num = num.replace("(", "")
num = num.replace(")", "")
num = num.replace("+7", "8")

res = re.findall(pattern, num)

print(res)
# ['8926123456', '8926123456', '7926123456', '8926123456', '8926123456', '1234567', '9261234567', '7926123456', '4951234567']
```